# Pandas: subtracting value from column (to find variations from it)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with this type of column:

```
magnetic_mag
34.451282394
44.81445845
24.833269553
25.032404588
22.027024464
```

I want to find the variation of every value from 30 (If the value is above 30 so I want to subtract 30 from it and if it's below I want to subtract the value itself from 30), so the output column in the data frame should look like this:

```
magnetic_mag
    4.451282394
    14.81445845
    5.166730447
    4.967595412
    7.972975536
```

Any easy way to do it with pandas ?

Edit:
If I want the values below 30 to be with (-) sign (negative) is it possible?
Desired output:

```
magnetic_mag
        4.451282394
        14.81445845
        -5.166730447
        -4.967595412
        -7.972975536
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just subtract 30 and call [abs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html):

```
(df["magnetic_mag"] - 30).abs()
Out[23]: 
0     4.451282
1    14.814458
2     5.166730
3     4.967595
4     7.972976
Name: magnetic_mag, dtype: float64
```

Comment: And if I want the negative values to be negative is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

A variation:

```
import numpy as np

np.where(df['magnetic_mag']>30, df['magnetic_mag']-30, 30-df['magnetic_mag'])
#Out[100]: array([  4.45128239,  14.81445845,   5.16673045,   4.96759541,   7.97297554])
```